# Are intonation issues in a cheap acoustic guitar fixable?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings, maintenance, intonation, lutherie

so I am a beginner guitarist, and I have one quite good guitar, and a cheap one.
I`ve tuned it to standard tuning, and when I play the 5th fret on the E string on the cheap one, it goes like 1/4 of a note higher of A. And when I go to the 10th fret, it goes like third of a note higher (15th is almost half a note higher)
Do you know if this is fixable (maybe by lowering the bridge or something), and if yes, how?
(btw English is not my native language, sorry)

Comment: It's called intonation, and bad intonation can be caused by different things. Without inspecting the guitar it's hard to say what is causing it. https://www.fender.com/articles/tech-talk/intonation-101

Comment: Is it just the E string or do all of them go out of tune at the same frets.  Sound like it could use an adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

If the action isn't so high that the string is being stretched to too sharp, it's most likely the bridge or its saddles are too close to the nut. It may not be an adjustable bridge, in which case there's little you can do. Sounds like it needs moving 2 or 3 mm back, which may well be impossible.